# VirtualBox 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 do not see FortiClient interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn

I'm running a Windows10 virtual machine with VirtualBox 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04.
I'm connected to a VPN thanks FortiClient with my Ubuntu and it's works well.
A new "*fctvpn42f76226*" interface is visible thanks "*ifconfig*".

ifconfig "fctvpn42f76226":
[image: ifconfig "fctvpn42f76226"]

To have access from Windows10 VM to this VPN, I add a NAT interface and I was thinking to add a bridge interface to the "*fctvpn42f76226*" but VirtualBox do not show this interface.

VirtualBox interfaces:
[image: VirtualBox interfaces]

Two questions please:

- is it the right solution to add a bridge?
- is it normal that VirtualBox do not show all interfaces?

Then, I have tried to use FortiClient on Windows10 with a NAT to connect to Internet but FortiClient fails with "The server you want to connect to requests identification, please choose a certificate and try again. (-6005)"